# How can I shut down a program at certain temperature and restart again when temperature is low?

Tags: windows, batch-file, temperature, heat

I want a way to shut down a program when my temp reaches 80+ but when it's lower than 70 I want it to start again. Do I ask too much? :(

Comment: Perhaps one of the programs mentioned in this post can help http://superuser.com/questions/395434/how-can-i-check-the-temperature-of-my-cpu-in-windows

Comment: I know that coretemp doesn't have any command line options, but you can set it to log a file. If you're able to start by doing something like that, then providing an example of the log output here, I can probably help.

Comment: You'd need to tell us which of the many applications to monitor the CPU temperature you are using.

Comment: I use CPUID HWMonitor to monitor my temperatures.

Comment: you can use `wmic` to get the temperature and kill a process.

Comment: @endoro Good plan, but I don't seem to have temperature in my CPU for any core `wmic cpu list full`

Comment: @foxidrive have you tried `wmic temperature` ?

Comment: Endoro can I do that automaticly?

Comment: @endoro `wmic temperature list full` only returns `No Instance(s) Available.`  Is it CPU specific?

Comment: @foxidrive I tested it here on 5 PCs with no success :/ also not with `wmic path CIM_TemperatureSensor`  and `wmic path Win32_TemperatureProbe` .